# How to write a post to my facebook app's wall from app engine using python?

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine

I have an app engine web app that would like to automatically write a post to the wall of a facebook application I control (i.e. every time a particular event occurs on the website I would like to update the wall of my facebook application).

This code will be called from a deferred task on the server.

I have been unable to find anything addressing this. Your help would be appreciated.

First thing I did was get my access token with the following code:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID&client_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_pages,offline_access
```

Using the returned access token this is what I'm running on the server:

```
form_fields = {
    "access_token": FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    "message": tgText
    };

form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
result = urlfetch.fetch(url="https://graph.facebook.com/MYAPP_FACEBOOK_ID/feed",
                        payload=form_data,
                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                        validate_certificate=False,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

But calling this results in:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an administrator you can grant access to third party apps (e.g. your python app) to post onto your App's Profile Page (http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=YOUR_APP_ID) using OAuth:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ (Section **Page Login**)

Once you received an access token you should be able to post to App Profile Page as described here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ (Section **Publishing**)

Comment: I updated the question based on your feedback, but I'm still not getting it to work - for some reason it doesn't recognize my code as authorized.

Comment: You are using the wrong url to fetch the access token. As pointed out in my response, check out section "Page Login" of the authentication flow. The access token url in that section contains "scope=manage_pages", which essentially grants your app access to all the Facebook pages you are an administrator of. After that you post directly to the page (using the page id, not your app id in the feed url). of course this requires you to create a Facebook Page for your app first.

Comment: Actually, the last part is wrong, I just found out that every app already has a page, so you won't have to create it and apparently you can use the same id. Therefore try simply replacing the access token url. Let us know if it worked and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: That worked better.  I got a response that led me to believe that the post was accepted, and if I try to post the same again I get a "error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#506) Duplicate status message"}}, however it doesn't show up on the app's wall.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried querying your posts through the graph API? Also try to post something directly on the Page and check whether you receive it through the graph API. That way we now it's the correct feed you are posting to...

Comment: A little more fiddling and it's working. Your last comment got me looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar app.  Facebook can change the code that you're meant to submit as part of the process for gaining an access token.  I wrote a simple web page that creates a form with hidden input fields that contain the data required to get Facebook to authorise an app with a user (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).

When the user clicks the submit button, the browser does an HTTP GET to Facebook, with an appropriate query string, where the Facebook user is prompted to login (if needed) and authorise the app.  If authorised Facebook calls back your **redirect_url** with the code which you can store in the DataStore to retrieve when needed as part of the "give me an access token" flow.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help as I'm trying to do the posting from the server, not the browser (i.e. the user is the web server)